# In Databricks, I am facing org.postgresql.util.PSQLException : even I change postgres settings in my ubuntu 20.04

Tags: postgresql, pyspark, databricks

I am working on pyspark related project.but it is showing me in databricks:: ""org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.""

If any one has idea about that please share. Thank You!

Comment: A network problem. Either PostgreSQL isn't configured to listen at that interface, or y firewall intervenes.

Answer (score 0):

The PostgreSQL isn't running on the nodes of the Databricks cluster (see reference to `localhost`), it should run as a separate service somewhere - managed by the cloud provider, or running on VMs managed by your database team.

Most probably the reason for that is that `url` parameter doesn't have a correct host name.  See [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html) for examples.